# Hangfire.Mongo cannot be referenced in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: mongodb, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, hangfire

I did this:

1. Created new WebAPI project in Visual Studio 2013
2. Package Manager Console: Install-Package HangFire
3. Package Manager Console: Install-Package HangFire.Mongo
4. Put the example code in Global and created the example Startup class described here https://github.com/sergun/Hangfire.Mongo

When I compile I get the error `The type or namespace name 'Mongo' does not exist in the namespace 'Hangfire'` for `Hangfire.Mongo` namespace, but I clearly have the reference.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably are using an old target framework. It happened the same thing to me a while back.

Check your project properties -> Application -> Target framework and make sure it's at least .NET Framework 4.5.1

Comment: That was it! I had 4.5 and 4.5.1 was required.